# Can we create an RNN model with shared LSTM layer and Embedding layer?

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network, text-classification, word-embedding

I'm trying to build a model that consists of a uniform layer architecture that has a shared LSTM layer and an embedding layer. But I couldn't build it.

This is the model architecture:

[image: The architecture of my model is in this picture]

I need a code to build this model.

[The base paper of our required model is given here](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/16/Papers/408.pdf)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not really a coding question. You need to be specific, so someone with a similar model can find your question (and hopefully also the answer). No one is going to read an entire paper to find out what the problem is. Could you please share what did you try in what framework and in what way it did not work?